# Meaning of "manually" in "manually detect copyright infringement"

Tags: idiomatic-language

I saw AngryJoe, Youtuber, use this phrasing:

> manually detect copyright infringement

This sounds wrong to me. I thought "manual" meant "done with the hands". How can you manually detect something such as copyright infringement?

Comment: If you explain what it is that sounds wrong about it to you, we might be able to help. One point I note is that one meaning of _manually_ is _not using an automatic tool_.

Comment: I thought it meant done with the hand(s).

Comment: That is its original meaning, JJJJ, and in some contexts it still has that meaning. But words change and extend their meanings over time, and that is clearly not a relevant meaning for this example.

Comment: @JJJJ When users ask for clarification, it is better to edit your question than to answer with another comment. I will go ahead and make that change now for you, but you may want to keep that in mind for future questions.

Comment: @Tashus: good advice, but it is worth adding a line like **Edited to clarify** in the question, otherwise the existing comments may look incoherent or perverse.

Comment: @ColinFine Likewise good advice, but isn't a comment noting the edit preferred over explicitly referring to the edit process in the question, as that clutters things for future readers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Manually can refer to something done by a person rather than through an automated process.**

AngryJoe could be referring to having to search the internet for specific sentences of a copyrighted work to find out if it has been used elsewhere without permission.

The alternative would be to pay for a service that performs such scans for you on a regular basis and automatically sends you alerts if/when it detects possible infringements.